Issue With IK Not aligning correctly when chain link is applied to 2
I'm completely new to blender, and I am creating an FPS arms model. When I try to add the IK constraint to the model it bends slightly out which I am so confused as this is my first time creating models in blender. What am I doing wrong here?
I can send a file as well, but I'm not sure how to upload on here.
I heard about the pole roll as well but again, I am not sure what I'm doing wrong, and would love some feedback


You need to make sure about several things: In Edit mode bend the elbow a bit so that Bender knows how it is supposed to bend, stick the head of the target bone to the tail of the IK bone, also, once you have a pole target, correct the Pole Angle if necessary. If it still doesn't work use blend-exchange.com (read the instructions)
